# Solving equations with two parameters

Tags: equation-solving

There are two equations:

```
Integrate[1/Square(2*Cosh[y] - 2*Cosh[u]) , {y, z, u}] == 0.013

2*Cosh[z] - 2*Cosh[u] == 0.41
```

How can I obtain z and u?

Comment: What is `Square`? Did you mean `1/(2*Cosh[y] - 2*Cosh[u])^2`

Comment: Thanks. My bad. It should be Integrate[1/Sqrt[(2 Cosh[y] - 2 Cosh[u])],{y, z, u}] == 0.013]